# I have a problem when try to send SMS to my mobile by INFOBIP

Tags: java, sms, infobip, infobip-api

I have a problem when send SMS I get 200 http status but message is not received to my mobile.

THIS MY CODE

```
        try {
            // Create the connection to the Infobip API.
            URL url = new URL(BASE_URL + "/sms/2/text/advanced");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "App " + API_KEY);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
//            connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            // Create the SMS message JSON payload.
            String payload = String.format("{\"messages\":[{\"from\":\"%s\",\"destinations\":[{\"to\":\"%s\"}],\"text\":\"%s\"}]}",
                    SENDER,
                    RECIPIENT,
                    MESSAGE_TEXT
            );
            // Write the payload to the request.
            try (OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = payload.getBytes("utf-8");
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }

            // Get the response from the API.
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Message sent successfully. Response Content: " + response.toString());
                }
            } else {
                // Print the response content for error requests.
                // Similar to the success case, adjust the parsing and print the full response content.
                try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()))) {
                    String line;
                    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Error sending message. Response Content: " + response.toString());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Response Code: 200

This is response:

> Message sent successfully. Response Content: {"messages":[{"messageId":"3915723960824335774697","status":{"description":"Message sent to next instance","groupId":1,"groupName":"PENDING","id":26,"name":"PENDING_ACCEPTED"},"to":"970597086266"}]}

This response should be returned like this:

```
 groupId: 3
        groupName: DELIVERED
        id: 5
        name: DELIVERED_TO_HANDSET
        description: Message delivered to handset
        action: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Some time has passed and I am putting my comment here to help others not lose too much time on this.
I had a similar problem and while looking for some clues I found your question.

I was getting the same response when calling the API.

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "messageId": "SOME_MESSAGE_ID",
      "status": {
        "description": "Message sent to next instance",
        "groupId": 1,
        "groupName": "PENDING",
        "id": 26,
        "name": "PENDING_ACCEPTED"
      },
      "to": "SOME_PHONE_NUMBER"
    }
  ]
}
```

If you try to get some info about that messageID through the API again ( https://epqd3.api.infobip.com/sms/2/logs?messageId=THE_MESSAGE_ID ), you would get an empty response like:

```
{
    "results": []
}
```

If you try to check the dashboard in Infobip, there is no such request/message.

If you try to make a request via Postman (with SMS body as plain text), all is good and you can see the message in the dashboard.

[**Cause of the problem**]

Turned out the problem was that the content of the SMS was not in **PLAIN TEXT**! It was more like a rendered HTML encoded string.

[**Solution**]

For me it was just making sure the body of the SMS is in PLAIN TEXT. That solved  the problem for me.